# Postgresql 9.1 COuld not send stop signal. Operation not permitted

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have recently installed PostgreSQL 9.1 on my Mac and I'm trying unsuccessfully to start and stop it using the pg_ctl command.

The default installation folder for the data files is /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data

This is only accessible by 'postgres' by default (ie no permissions for anyone else), so I have had to change permissions on that folder (why install something that is unusable by default?)

However, issuing the command:

[mitch@localhost ~]$ /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_ctl -l ~/Library/Logs/postgreslog -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data stop

returns the error

pg_ctl: could not send stop signal (PID: 50): Operation not permitted

Anybody any idea how to get round this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I managed to figure this out...

I needed to use

sudo su - postgres

to change my login to the user postgres, which has the permission necessary to run the pg_ctl command and access the data folder also

Comment: I had the same issue on Windows : I had to execute the command as an administrator (open cmd.exe as an administrator).

Answer (score 0):

We got the same issue. so no need to any change in the file.

The following step we have resolve.

1. Search programs and files in start menu in `cmd`.
2. Right click cmd icon with Run As Administrator to open window command prompt.
3. Goto postgres bin directory `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin` using cd command in command prompt or set environment variable to all exe file within bin directory run as command.
4. execute command in command propmt `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/bin/pg_ctl -l ~/Library/Logs/postgreslog -D /Library/PostgreSQL/9.1/data stop`
   Let us know if you have problem again.